# Random characters after table name in FROM clause of SELECT query

Tags: postgresql

I am rather new to SQL and database administration. I am maintaining/modifying a PHP application that interacts with Postgresql, and have encountered the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM client_messages c;
```

I do not understand the meaning of the final 'c' character. In fact, it seems like it is possible to have random characters after the table name in the FROM clause of a SELECT, without affecting the results of the query. Experimenting with the 'psql' utility, I find that these three queries all produce the same result, without any errors:

```
SELECT * FROM cltk2980dat c LIMIT 5;
SELECT * FROM cltk2980dat LIMIT 5;
SELECT * FROM cltk2980dat kdopwijfdwlhoeufhnekfhyufhf LIMIT 5;
```

Yet, the author of the program I am maintaining seems to have really wanted that final 'c' character in the SELECT query. I cannot find any explanation for this in manuals of SQL syntax, though I can find explanations of many other ways to modify the FROM clause of a SELECT.

Is there some significance to that final character? Will apparently random characters after the FROM table-name ever have any significance under some circumstances?

Comment: It is a table alias. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM

Comment: So, just to be explicit, even if the word "AS" is omitted from the Query, the characters after the table name in the FROM clause are assumed to be an alias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @dezso points out it's a table alias. You can also use `as` which makes it a bit more comprehendable:

```
SELECT * FROM client_messages as c
```

Why use an alias? It makes it easier to refer to the table. Assume the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM client_messages
JOIN client_address
    ON client_messages.client_id = client_address.client_id
```

Using table aliases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM client_messages as cm
JOIN client_address as ca
    ON cm.client_id = ca.client_id
```

so it's a bit shorter which is nice. When using self joins it becomes necessary to use aliases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM client_messages as cm1
JOIN client_messages as cm2
    ON cm1.x = cm2.y
WHERE cm1.... = ...
```

Otherwise there is no way to determine which one of the two tables one is referring to.

As a side-note, avoid using `SELECT *` other than for ad-hoc querying.

Comment: I've  encountered and used table aliases, but the absence of the keyword 'AS' threw me off. I'm surprised that you can get away with that! Normally SQL seems very picky about syntax, or at any rate I almost never get a query right the first time.

Comment: It is valid SQL even without the `as`. You may find some interest in an sql-validator provided by a company caller Mimer: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml